# Automatic RVM installation

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, rvm

I am trying to have RVM and ruby installed in an Ubuntu 12 virtual machine without human interaction apart from the password prompts.

I created a shell script to do this that works pretty fine until I need to use RVM itself.

I am using multi-user installation.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
mainUser=`whoami`
echo "Installing as '${mainUser}'"
echo "Installing git..."
sudo -S apt-get install --yes curl git-core
echo "Installing RVM..."
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
echo "Adding ${mainuser} to RVM group..."
sudo adduser $mainUser rvm
newgrp rvm
```

From here things get weird.. I need to load dvm as a source. I want both my script to have this source and my user's bash_profile / bashrc. Anyway.. I know how to do it manually, but I can't have this done from the script. This is the last code I tried:

```
. "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"
rvm use ruby-head
rubyVersion=`rvm list | awk '/ruby-head/{print x;print};{x=$0}' | sed -n '/ruby-head/{g;1!p;};h' | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
rubyTest=${rubyVersion}@test
rvm use $rubyTest --create --default
```

The error I get is this:

```
test.sh: 7: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

If I simply try to use the full path, like this:

```
rvm=/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
$rvm use ruby-head
rubyVersion=`$rvm list | awk '/ruby-head/{print x;print};{x=$0}' | sed -n '/ruby-head/{g;1!p;};h' | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
rubyTest =${rubyVersion}@test
$rvm use $rubyTest --create --default
```

I get this error instead:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

I am clueless. Why can't I use `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`?

Is there a way to execute `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` for this user from the script?

I am not so good at shell script and Linux, so I appreciate any references and examples you could give.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I also tried:

```
source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

... and all it's variants. Same error: "RVM is not a function".

Comment: did you try doing something like `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is causing the issue.

I realised before that I would get errors in the lines with conditions in the script files, so I came across this page:

https://superuser.com/questions/552016/bash-script-not-found

As it happens, I was executing the script with the following command:

```
sh script.sh
```

Which means I was getting Dash instead of Bash.

To fix the issue I changed my code to have this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

And then I executed like this:

```
bash script.sh
```

And voilà... RVM works again!

Answer (score 1):

rvm is actually implemented as a shell function rather than an executable, which is why you can't just call /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm itself.

Quoting you, "Is there a way to execute source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh for this user from the script?"

Have you tried doing that?  I had a somewhat similar install once where it didn't work properly from crontab (they have instructions on the site for that scenario, but we couldn't make them work), and I had to do almost exactly that -- source part of the profile.d for rvm.

Comment: Hi Some Guy! Thanks. Yes, I tried executing from the script. The $PATH, for example, doesn't change for this user, so I do `PATH="${PATH}:${rvm}"` to accomplish that. But I am trying to have dvm working in the script first. Executing it from the script renders the same error "RVM is not a function". It doesn't make sense to me, that's why I am asking here, I must be missing something. I didn't know about RVM not being an executable, thanks for that.

Comment: It's actually a kind of funky hybrid executable/shell function, depending on what it needs to do.  Some more info here: https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting

Answer (score 0):

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

Above error is generated when rvm is not running and hence your terminal is not able to recognize it, as it tries to run it as a system command.

You may want to try this to run rvm through your shell script before calling rvm methods:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it won't work, as I said, this is a multi-user installation, not single-user. Also, as far as I understand, the line `. "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"` is exactly the same as `source "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"`.

Comment: I guess you are right. Sorry didn't gave much attention to multi-user install